# Visual Basic Request: Delete files of a particular extension but omit filenames of the same extension which are found in a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-files, vb.net-2010, delete-file

I have a question I have tried searching around but I cannot seem to find tutorials on it.

I am hoping to use a console application to delete files of a particular extension for example .zip files but omit the deletion of files with the same extension whose filenames are located in a text file.

Example of the contents in the text file:

Folder1\filename1.zip

Folder2\filename2.zip

Filename3.zip

Filename4.zip

Each filenames are written on a separate line in the text file. As you can see some of the zip files are in the root directory where the console application is in and some are in folders in the root directory.

I tried using My.computer.filesystem.getfiles and search all levels for "*.zip" and then I was unable to continue as I am not sure how to delete all the zip files that are not found in the text file.

It would be deeply grateful if someone can show me a sample code on how to make this work in a console application.

If it is not too much trouble is it also possible to show a sample code for the reverse where only zip files whose filenames are in the text file are deleted.

I notice that when there are characters such as ' and ~ in the file names and an illegal character error will be displayed each time I try to delete the file using My.computer.filesystem.deletefile (if I remember the code correctly). I tried searching for tutorials but it did not work for me. If it is possible can the code sample shown address this problem as well. It would be good to also explain how it works if possible as I am curious to know how the code would work. Thank you.

Sorry I am still a beginner hence, trying to read from others sample codes to understand how it works and apply it. Thank you. Appreciate it.

I am currently using Visual Basic programming language to code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't name the file with illegal character, so how you want to delete it ?

```
 Dim txtFile As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("PATH Here")
        Dim TheNewJ As New List(Of String)
        For Each Path As String In Split(txtFile, vbCrLf)
            If Path.Trim <> "" Then
                If Path.EndsWith(".zip") Then
                        If IO.File.Exists(Path) Then
                        TheNewJ.Add(Path)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        txtFile = Join(TheNewJ.ToArray, vbCrLf + vbCrLf) '2 of vbcrlf to add the line,1 without line
```

Comment: Weird I thought you can name files with ' or ~ in it. I will try to show an example when I am back home.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help. Appreciate it. I will try the code later. :)

Comment: Yes you can name the file with ' or ~ but these chars are not illegal characters.